# Retrieving an xml string more than 65536 Characters in length via mssql_execute in PHP from a remote server

Tags: php, sql-server, xml

I'm working on a linux server (OPENSuSE // Apache 2 // PHP5) that connects to an MSSQL db on a Windows server and executes a stored procedure to retrieve an xml string which is passed back to the linux server as part of an array.

It works for the most part, but I'm now seeing issues with one or two rows where the xml is more than 65536 characters in length - they seem to be being curtailed - is this an issue which can be fixed in php.ini or is it a problem with the set up of the mssql server?

I may not have given enough information so please ask away and I'll provide as much as I can.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing the values as text, store them in a blob (or other binary format), and compress them first (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php)

The blob doesn't have a max length, so you wont run into issues, and you'll save on back and forth by compressing the data.

Comment: Or just store the XML file... as a file!

Comment: I'm normally against storing file like data in a database, but it does grant the opportunity to handle things in an atomic manner with transactions, and leaves you with a single point of backup rather than multiple.

Comment: No option with regards to the schema of the other database - it's existed for years and works for them, it is how it is. My question is more about whether anything will limit string length on the PHP side - ie will PHP end the array value at a certain number of chars or is it the output from the SP?

Comment: PHP can handle strings of arbitrary length. There's no built in limit (though you may run into a memory limit at some point). I had a similar issue building XHGUI where I stored serialized performance data in a database, I hit the 64k row limit and data was truncated. I compressed before I sent and things got much better.